# Sumar valores de una columna mientras el id sea el mismo a otro campo que esta repetido

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla con diferentes campos los cuales son los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podemos ver en la imagen hay una columna que se llama Control, la cual en el caso de forma de pago 4(cheque) es igual al id, pero en la forma de pago 104(consignación al cheque) es el id del cheque al cual pertenece esa consignación, lo que necesito es un select que me traiga los valores de la fila que tenga el "Forma_id = 4" pero con la respectiva suma de los valores del importe al cual corresponde.

Tengo el siguiente código el cual permite ver el la suma de los importes agrupados por el valor de control.

```
SELECT control, SUM(importe) AS Resultado 
FROM test.gestion_registro g2 
GROUP BY g2.control
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este otro código que me agrupa todo con respecto al campo control

```
SELECT g1.* 
FROM test.gestion_registro g1 
where g1.id IN (SELECT control 
                FROM test.gestion_registro g2 
                GROUP BY g2.control);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Básicamente es juntar las dos consultas en una sola. Espero encontrar una solución. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar una subconsulta en el select de tu segunda consulta para conseguirlo, algo como:

```
SELECT 
    g1.id,
    g1.lote,
    g1.control,
    g1.importe,
    g1.forma_id
    (select sum(importe) from test.gestion_registro g3 where g3.control = g1.control group by g3.control)
FROM 
    test.gestion_registro g1 
where 
    g1.id IN (SELECT control  FROM test.gestion_registro g2 GROUP BY g2.control);
```

Te dejo un ejemplo hecho en [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1d7eb/2)

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! Era justo lo que necesitaba!!!